# Convert data frame with structured spatial information to polygons

Tags: r

I have multiple tables that each look like that, x and y being the coordinates in WG84:

```
structure(list(x = c(-0.652363144524641, -0.652363144524641, 
-0.626050598958539, -0.626050598958539), y = c(49.0745447700184, 
49.0562285023707, 49.0562285023707, 49.0745447700184), L1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1), L2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I know that the original data was of type polygon because I saved them as data.frames using the function sf::st_coordinates. I did not know that I would need to use the data for a different purpose later. Now I would like to convert each of these tables to a spatial object, my final goal is to create a raster with the different polygons. And now that I want to use the tables I saved, I wonder whether it is possible at all to convert them back to polygon, or if I have to create the original polygons again from scratch...

Any feedback would be welcome.

**EDIT :**
To answer the question of @Chris, this is one of the polygons before using sf::st_coordinates (it is a square):

```
structure(list(patches = 1L, geometry = structure(list(structure(list(
    structure(c(3.61026923718395, 3.61026923718395, 3.63658178275005, 
    3.63658178275005, 3.61026923718395, 50.466581111243, 50.4482648435953, 
    50.4482648435953, 50.466581111243, 50.466581111243), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 3.61026923718395, 
ymin = 50.4482648435953, xmax = 3.63658178275005, ymax = 50.466581111243
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "GEOGCRS[\"unknown\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",8901]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]]", 
    wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"unknown\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",8901]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(patches = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = 1L, class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"))
```

and after

```
structure(list(x = c(3.61026923718395, 3.61026923718395, 3.63658178275005, 
3.63658178275005, 3.61026923718395), y = c(50.466581111243, 50.4482648435953, 
50.4482648435953, 50.466581111243, 50.466581111243), L1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), L2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have some decisions to make regarding the order of your x or y, depending, as polygons are 'closed' by having the first and last numeric value the same

```
poly_maybe = list(x = c(-0.652363144524641, -0.652363144524641, 
-0.626050598958539, -0.626050598958539), y = c(49.0745447700184, 
49.0562285023707, 49.0562285023707, 49.0745447700184))

 poly_mtx = matrix(cbind(poly_maybe$x, poly_maybe$y), nrow = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, c('x', 'y'))

plot(sf::st_polygon(list(poly_mtx)))
Error in MtrxSet(x, dim, type = "POLYGON", needClosed = TRUE) : 
  polygons not (all) closed

# or

poly_mtx[, 1] = poly_mtx[c(3,1,2,4), 1]
sf::st_polygon(list(poly_mtx))
POLYGON ((-0.6260506 49.07454, -0.6523631 49.05623, -0.6523631 49.05623, -0.6260506 49.07454))
```

and you have POLYGON, though in this case it plots like a line.

Using your final `structure(` above

```
points_df <- structure(list(x = c(3.61026923718395, 3.61026923718395, 3.63658178275005, 
3.63658178275005, 3.61026923718395), y = c(50.466581111243, 50.4482648435953, 
50.4482648435953, 50.466581111243, 50.466581111243), L1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), L2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

matrix(c(points_df$x, points_df$y), nrow = nrow(points_df), ncol = 2)
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 3.610269 50.46658
[2,] 3.610269 50.44826
[3,] 3.636582 50.44826
[4,] 3.636582 50.46658
[5,] 3.610269 50.46658

st_polygon(list(matrix(c(points_df$x, points_df$y), nrow = nrow(points_df), ncol = 2)))
POLYGON ((3.610269 50.46658, 3.610269 50.44826, 3.636582 50.44826, 3.636582 50.46658, 3.610269 50.46658)) 

plot(st_polygon(list(matrix(c(points_df$x, points_df$y), nrow = nrow(points_df), ncol = 2))))
```

And we have 'POLYGON'. Just have to think through some tests that could be applied to input data.frames to set our expectations about results.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know the order. What about the L1 and L2 columns created by sf::st_coordinates? I thought that they could be used to define the closure of polygons, but I don't know how.

Comment: Stepping back in your process, do any of the pre `sf::st_coords(polygon` polygon inputs still exist?

Comment: I provided a more reproducible example as edit to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for 1 polygon. But not for a table with several polygons (which is my case, and it was not very clear looking at my question, sorry). I found out how to use L1 and L2 to restore the different polygons, I will write it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a table with several polygons with L1 and L2 columns, as it is the case in the question, this is the solution developped based on the answer of @Chris.

As explained in help(st_coordinates): "For POLYGONS, L1 can be used to identify exterior rings and inner holes. The exterior ring is when L1 is equal to 1. Interior rings are identified when L1 is greater than 1. L2 can be used to differentiate between the feature. "

This solution is not very elegant but it worked:

```
Table_1 = structure(list(x = c(3.61026923718395, 3.61026923718395, 3.63658178275005, 
3.63658178275005, 3.61026923718395), y = c(50.466581111243, 50.4482648435953, 
50.4482648435953, 50.466581111243, 50.466581111243), L1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), L2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

for(k in 1:length(names(table(Table_1$L2)))){
  outer_k = matrix(c(Table_1$x[which(Table_1$L1==1 & Table_1$L2==k)], # exterior rings
                     Table_1$y[which(Table_1$L1==1 & Table_1$L2==k)]), 
                   nrow = nrow(Table_1[which(Table_1$L1==1 & Table_1$L2==k),]), 
                   ncol = 2) 
  if(exists("list_k")){rm(list_k)}
  for (l in 1:length(names(table(Table_1$L1[which(Table_1$L2==k)])))){ # different holes
    hole_l = matrix(c(Table_1$x[which(Table_1$L1==l & Table_1$L2==k)],
                      Table_1$y[which(Table_1$L1==l & Table_1$L2==k)]), 
                    nrow = nrow(Table_1[which(Table_1$L1==l & Table_1$L2==k),]), 
                    ncol = 2)
    if(exists("list_k")){
      list_k[[l]] = hole_l
    }else{
      list_k = list(outer_k, hole_l) # create one list (exterior ring + holes) for each L2 feature
    } 
  }
  if(exists("c_final")){
    c_final = c(c_final, st_polygon(list_k))
  }else{
    c_final = st_polygon(list_k)
  }
}

plot(c_final)
```

Comment: I respect elegant, but it is great to get something working, and this both works and really does some checking - I hadn't considered holes & etc.